# Replacing All References to a Variable By C++ #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Not sure if anyone has this experience in maintaining old codes. In some old codes, I have a global variable referenced in many places.  I want to replace all those references to my global variable to something else, say a function call.  Can I do it by a simple #define in every source file? e.g.

```
#define legacyGlobalVariable func1("legacyGlobalVariable")
```

My *func1()* will accept the name of the old variable and return something same type as the *legacyGlobalVariable*.

I know #define can replace *legacyGlobalVariable* that forms a token.  But I am not sure if there are any special cases that this simple technique cannot handle.  For example, I know I need to prevent this:

```
legacyGlobalVariable(23);// a badly named function same name as my global var
```

becoming

```
func1("legacyGlobalVariable")(23);//but at least, it cannot compile
```

Are there any other possible issues with this simple technique?  Did anyone ever try using it?  I know to verify all the possible cases really require familiarity with C++ which is beyond my grasp for the time being.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why global variables are to be avoided. As you have experienced first-hand, it makes maintenance much harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

The primary issue with it is that [`#define` is evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.8). This will not improve the readability of your code, so I'd recommend just biting the bullet and use your editor's find/replace function instead.

Comment: Use your editor's find/replace to replace the global variable with a function call (so the OP never has to do the find/replace again).

Answer (score 1):

***Are there any other possible issues with this simple technique?***
Yes! What about parameter type checking?
For a function arguments are checked for type and compilers return errors if type mismatch. With macros there is no such type checking.

Also, macros often leave you with lot of unimaginable side effects.

You are far better off replacing it with a function rather than mapping the function through macro.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, if the code is old enough and is working fine then **better not change** anything. Follow the software industry rule of, "Don't touch anything until it's needed."

Why you want to waste your time/effort to change a legacy code and testing it in various scenarios, rather than learning to develop something new. In case if something is broken due to the change, then you will end up spending more time on fixing that rather than actual maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some scripting language e.g. perl
and automate your find and replace,
That'd give you more control

e.g. you can easily avoid instances like this from being modified

func1("legacyGlobalVariable")(23)

it saves you a lot of time also.